# Python- run socket script on the remote linux host

Tags: python, sockets, chat, authentication

I have uploaded the server script to the public directory on the server machine. Then I try to connect to the server by a client, but I am not being connected. Here is my code snippets:

```
# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = 'www.dotpy.ir/server.py'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

server:

```
# Echo server program
import socket 
HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

These scripts seem to work well.

However, the script at the server must be run on the server for this to work. It's not enough for it to be uploaded to the public file area. What access do you have to the servers? Can you have scripts running on them?

If you succeed in running the script, then you will have to change the client script from:

```
HOST = 'www.dotpy.ir/server.py'    # The remote host
```

to

```
HOST = 'www.dotpy.ir'    # The remote host
```

The reason is that you will connect to the host itself. There the script will be running, listening to any inbound connections on the port specified. You can't conect to a specific script.

Good luck!